# Unknown Errors in my code

Tags: java

I am getting three errors when I run this code but have no idea what they are since this was provided skeleton code. I'll post the code and maybe someone could help me out. It might be a missing library or something simple but I would appreciate someones help. The errors are saying "cannot find symbol" for Sorter (towards the bottom of code) which I realize is not imported so is there an easier way to get around this?

```
package sort;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class AnimationTester implements ActionListener
{

private String algorithm="heap";    //Algoritm to sort by
private int elements=20;            //Number of elements to sort
private int delay=20;                 //speed to sort at
private Panel panel;       //The display Panel
private Thread t;           //A Thread for running sorts


/**
 * Creates an Animation Tester object and tells it to go.
 * This lets everything happen.
 * @param args The standard parameter
 * 
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    (new AnimationTester()).go();
}



/**
 * Launches the Sorting animation.
 * Creates a GUI
 */
private void go(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sort Demo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    panel = new Panel();
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);



    //    Where the GUI is created:
    JMenuBar menu;
    JMenu sort,num,delay; 



    //      Create the menu bar.
    menu = new JMenuBar();

    //      Build the first menu.
    sort = new JMenu("Algorithm");
    sort.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    sort.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
                            "Choose an algorithm");

    //      a group of radio button menu items


    JRadioButtonMenuItem bubble = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Bubble Sort");
    bubble.setActionCommand("bubble");
    JRadioButtonMenuItem merge = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Merge Sort");
    merge.setActionCommand("merge");
    JRadioButtonMenuItem heap = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Heap Sort");
    heap.setActionCommand("heap");
    heap.setSelected(true);
    JRadioButtonMenuItem insert = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Insertion Sort");
    insert.setActionCommand("insert");
    JRadioButtonMenuItem quick = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Quick Sort");
    quick.setActionCommand("quick");
    JRadioButtonMenuItem shell = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Shell Sort");
    shell.setActionCommand("shell");
    JRadioButtonMenuItem selection = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Selection Sort");
    selection.setActionCommand("select");

    //Group the radio buttons.
    ButtonGroup group1 = new ButtonGroup();
    group1.add(bubble);
    group1.add(merge);
    group1.add(heap);
    group1.add(insert);
    group1.add(quick);
    group1.add(shell);
    group1.add(selection);
    sort.add(bubble);
    sort.add(merge);
    sort.add(heap);
    sort.add(insert);
    sort.add(quick);
    sort.add(shell);
    sort.add(selection);

    bubble.addActionListener(this);
    merge.addActionListener(this);
    heap.addActionListener(this);
    insert.addActionListener(this);
    quick.addActionListener(this);
    shell.addActionListener(this);
    selection.addActionListener(this);


    //      Build second menu in the menu bar.
    num = new JMenu("Elements");
    num.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    num.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
                            "How many elements?");

    //      a group of radio button menu items


    JRadioButtonMenuItem n10 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("10");
    n10.setActionCommand("10");
    JRadioButtonMenuItem n20 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("20");
    n20.setActionCommand("20");
    n20.setSelected(true);
    JRadioButtonMenuItem n30 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("30");
    n30.setActionCommand("30");    
    JRadioButtonMenuItem n50 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("50");
    n50.setActionCommand("50");
    JRadioButtonMenuItem n100 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("100");
    n100.setActionCommand("100");

    //Group the radio buttons.
    ButtonGroup group2 = new ButtonGroup();
    group2.add(n10);
    group2.add(n20);
    group2.add(n30);
    group2.add(n50);
    group2.add(n100);
    num.add(n10);
    num.add(n20);
    num.add(n30);
    num.add(n50);
    num.add(n100);

    n10.addActionListener(this);
    n20.addActionListener(this);
    n30.addActionListener(this);
    n50.addActionListener(this);
    n100.addActionListener(this);

    //    Build third menu in the menu bar.


    delay = new JMenu("Speed delay");
    delay.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    delay.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
                                "How slow?");

    //      a group of radio button menu items


    JRadioButtonMenuItem s0 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("0");
    s0.setActionCommand("s000");
    JRadioButtonMenuItem s20 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("20");
    s20.setActionCommand("s020");
    s20.setSelected(true);
    JRadioButtonMenuItem s50 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("50");
    s50.setActionCommand("s050");
    JRadioButtonMenuItem s100 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("100");
    s100.setActionCommand("s100");
    JRadioButtonMenuItem s500 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("500");
    s500.setActionCommand("s500");

    //Group the radio buttons.
    ButtonGroup group3 = new ButtonGroup();
    group3.add(s0);
    group3.add(s20);
    group3.add(s50);
    group3.add(s100);
    group3.add(s500);
    delay.add(s0);
    delay.add(s20);
    delay.add(s50);
    delay.add(s100);
    delay.add(s500);

    s0.addActionListener(this);
    s20.addActionListener(this);
    s50.addActionListener(this);
    s100.addActionListener(this);
    s500.addActionListener(this);


    //add the menus to the Menubar
    menu.add(sort);
    menu.add(num);
    menu.add(delay);

    frame.setJMenuBar(menu);

    frame.setVisible(true);


    startSort();


}

/**
 * Launches a sort.
 * If a sort is already in progress, does nothing.
 *
 */
private void startSort(){
    //do not sort if already busy sorting.
    if(t!=null&&t.isAlive()) return;
    Double[] values = new Double[elements];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
        values[i] = new Double(Math.random() * panel.getHeight()); 
    Runnable r = new Sorter(panel, values, algorithm, delay);
    t=new Thread(r);
    t.start();
}



/**
 * Detects menu commands
 * @param e The event that occured
 */
public synchronized void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String s=e.getActionCommand();
    if(s=="bubble"||s=="merge"||s=="heap"||
       s=="insert"||s=="quick"||
       s=="shell"||s=="select"){
        algorithm=s;
        startSort();
    }
    if(s=="10"||s=="20"||s=="30"||
       s=="50"||s=="100"){
        elements=Integer.parseInt(s);
        startSort();
    }

    if(s=="s000"||s=="s020"||s=="s050"||
       s=="s100"||s=="s500"){
        delay=Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1,4));
    }



}

//private static final int VALUES_LENGTH = 30;
private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400;
private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 400;
}
```

Comment: Do you have classes `ArrayComponent` and `Sorter` somewhere?

Comment: Make sure classes `ArrayComponent` and `Sorter` are in your class path

Comment: Can you put your StackTrace .

Comment: You should import the `ArrayComponent`  and `Sorter` classs properly in your source

Comment: Well this is provided skeleton code I am just trying to get it to work. I've tried researching what to do but it seems like a vague error. @gk1017 is there a special way I should import them.

Comment: From my understandin i guess those 2 are the classes . So you can  import as normal way like.. import pakg.ArrayComponent;import pakg.Sorter; its so simple

Answer (score 1):

Hi I checked you code and found that neither ArrayComponent nor Sorter were imported in your class..

even if you have included them in your class path, until they are in the same package as this class they wont be implicitly imported.

use import statement as

```
import ArrayComponent ;
import Sorter;
```

then it must work

Comment: Well see this was the only file given so there isn't a place that I can import them from. Could I use any substitutes for these two things given what they are being used for in the program?

Comment: I used Panel class instead of ArrayComponent but Sorter Class is unclear to me as to what it does..

and this code was given to u..??..did you try to understand what it does..??

did u try to get the related jars for this code..??

Comment: Yes I realized that the panel class would work soon after I posted that last comment haha but by going through the code I believe it is suppose to animate the sorting algorithms provided through various threads. The only thing I can't figure out is that Sorter..

Comment: check with your team or whatever..giving solution for sorter class will be useless if i didn't know the functionality

Comment: well it looks like its where the sorting algorithm is chosen along with what values to sort with a delay time and then put into a thread